# can we declare an object of another class as the data member

Tags: c#

My code is like this...

```
class Transaction
{
    public class Date
    {
        public int day, month, year;
    }
    Date d;
    double amount;
    long acc_no;
    string action;
}
```

how can we access the Date d.

Comment: From where? Yes you can do it. Note that nesting classes is something you should do only if you *know* its a good idea. Most of the time you don't want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> how can we access the Date d

Same way you access any class-level member of any object.

From within any instance of the class `Transaction`, you would access it as a class-level member:

```
this.d
```

From outside an instance of `Transaction` you can't access `d` (nor should you) because it's a private member.  (C# members are private by default unless declared otherwise.)

From within an instance of `Date` there's no guarantee that you're in the context of an instance of `Transaction` so there's no direct access to that member.  (Just because it's a nested class doesn't guarantee that it will always be used in that structure.)  Not that it would really matter anyway since `d` is an instance of `Date` so if you're in `Date` then it would only need to access itself anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comment, this is generally not a good idea, but you can access it. You can access it from anywhere in class Transaction, but not outside it, unless you use a method or property.

```
class Transaction
{
    public class Date
    {
        public int day, month, year;
    }
    Date d;
    double amount;
    long acc_no;
    string action;


    public Date GetDate()
    {
        return d; // Access Date d by using a method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

namespace banking
{

public class Transaction
    {
        public class Date
        {
            public int day, month, year;
        }
        public Date date = new Date();
        public double amount;
        public long acc_no;
        public string action;
    }

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Transaction> transaction = new List<Transaction>();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("transaction.csv");
        string data = sr.ReadLine();
        while (data != null)
        {
            string[] dataarray = data.Split(',');
            string[] date_split = dataarray[0].Split('-');

            Transaction tran_obj = new Transaction();

            tran_obj.date.day = int.Parse(date_split[0]);
            tran_obj.date.month = int.Parse(date_split[1]);
            tran_obj.date.year = int.Parse(date_split[2]);

            tran_obj.acc_no = long.Parse(dataarray[1]);
            tran_obj.amount = double.Parse(dataarray[2]);
            tran_obj.action = dataarray[3];

            transaction.Add(tran_obj);
            data = sr.ReadLine();

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the account number for which you are looking for");
        long new_acc_no = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        foreach (Transaction t in transaction)
        {
            if (t.acc_no == new_acc_no)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.amount);
                Console.WriteLine(t.date);
                Console.WriteLine(t.action);

            }
        }

        string s = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}

the problem with this code is that in output console it is not showing the date
i have stored the date like this 12-02-1994